# Returning the superagent response object from a function

Tags: node.js, superagent

I'm using [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) to make HTTP API calls from Node.s and here's how my code looks like right now:

```
async function getProjectParameterValue(projectId, parameter) {
    let projectParamsUrl = "some/endpoint" + projectId + "/parameters/";
    let url = "http://baseUrl/" + projectParamsUrl + parameter;
    return await superagent.get(url).auth(userName, password)
        .type('json')
        .accept('json')
        .then(response => {
            return response.body;
        })
        .then(responseBody => {
            return responseBody;
        });
}
```

In this case, the function `getProjectParameterValue` returns a promise which has to be resolved after calling it outside, like this:

```
getProjectParameterValue("myProjectId", "someParameter")
    .then(responseBody => {
       log.info(responseBody);
    });
```

I'm looking for some way to have the function `getProjectParameterValue` return the superagent response object directly. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Cant you try `return response` instead of `return response.body` inside the `getProjectParameterValue` ?

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of minor things:

1. A Promise resolves to its returned value
2. A Promise resolves when the aync behaviour its is waiting for is complete
3. You can 'await' the resolved value of a Promise, or return the Promise and use .then() to create a new Promise with a new resolved value

In your example. Your Promise resolves to the body of the response, as such anyone who is using that Promise will only have access to the response body.

As such you want to resolve the response itself rather than the body.

Note also that when returning a Promise there is no need to add an aync/await. All this is doing is adding another .then() that resolves to the existing resolved value, which is unnecessary

```
function getProjectParameterValue(projectId, parameter) {
    const url = `http://baseUrl/some/endpoint${projectId}/parameters/${parameter}`;

    return superagent
      .get(url)
      .auth(userName, password)
      .accept('json');
}

getProjectParameterValue("myProjectId", "someParameter")
    .then((res) => {
       log.info(res.body);
    });
```

Alternative with await:

```
function getProjectParameterValue(projectId, parameter) {
    const url = `http://baseUrl/some/endpoint${projectId}/parameters/${parameter}`;

    return superagent
      .get(url)
      .auth(userName, password)
      .accept('json');
}

const res = await getProjectParameterValue("myProjectId", "someParameter")
log.info(res.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using promises like given below.

```
function getProjectParameterValue(projectId, parameter) {
    let projectParamsUrl = "some/endpoint" + projectId + "/parameters/";
    let url = "http://baseUrl/" + projectParamsUrl + parameter;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        superagent.get(url).auth(userName, password)
        .type('json')
        .accept('json')
        .then(response => {
            //you can manupulate result set as per requirements. 
            return response.body
        })
        .then(result => {
            resolve(result)
        });
       };
  });

}
```

And call function like this:

```
(async () => {
    const responseBody = await getProjectParameterValue("myProjectId", "someParameter")
})();
```

Comment: This solution works, but I'm not sure if I should be using it, since I would have multiple such functions called back-to-back synchronously and I'm afraid my code wouldn't be readable with this approach.

Comment: Okay. What if I need to add more such calls back-to-back? How would I achieve that with this approach?

Comment: You can add much callback as many as you like above. A reply has been updated. Please check